# Is any way can download file from Azure File(not blob) share by powershell

Tags: powershell, azure, azure-files

I want download a large file from the Azure File storage by powershell,
I found all the solution are use the Azure blobs, it's can not work with Azure files,

Is any way to download the file from Azure files?

[Note:because the file is very big(127GB) and will cost much time to download it(may need 3~4days), so it always broken when I using the browser to download it]

below is the official document: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/storage-powershell-guide-full

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use the following cmdlets to download a file from Azure File Share.

```
$ctx = New-AzureStorageContext [storageaccountname] [storageaccountkey]
##sharename is your existed name.
$s = Get-AzureStorageShare [sharename] –Context $ctx
##To download a file from the share to the local computer, use Get-AzureStorageFileContent.
Get-AzureStorageFileContent –Share $s –Path [path to file on the share] [path on local computer]
```

If you want to download multiple files using one command, you could use [Azcopy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/storage-use-azcopy).

```
AzCopy /Source:https://myaccount.file.core.windows.net/myfileshare/ /Dest:C:\myfolder /SourceKey:key /S
```

More information please refer to this [link](https://robindotnet.wordpress.com/2014/07/09/azure-files-how-to-manage-shares-directories-and-files/).

Answer (score 6):

You can do it in 3 ways

**1. Azure Storage Explorer**

Install azure storage explorer in any windows, you can download files from there

[image]

**2. AZ COPY**

Execute the below command in powershell to download your file from azure blob

Execute below command like this in powershell

```
&'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Azure\AzCopy\AzCopy.exe' /Source:https://<STORAGE-ACCOUNT-NAME>.blob.core.windows.net/test-adf /Dest:'C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL13.SQLEXPRESS\MSSQL\Backup' /SourceKey:<BLOB-KEY> /S /XO
```

**3. Azure File Service**

You can connect your blob as an external drive so that you can easily copy your file